# Countdown changed by changing gmt of system(pc) clock

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Hi guys need some help,

here is my code

```
function getCurrentDateByGMT(finalTimezone){
    var now = new Date();
    var localTime = now.getTime();
    var finalGMT = now.getTimezoneOffset() - finalTimezone;
    var localOffset =  finalGMT * 60000;  // where 60000 is equals to 1 min
    return new Date(localTime + localOffset);
}
```

this function gets the current date by inputed gmt -480 where gmt + 8 multiplied by -60

but whenever i changed my computer timezone  the countdown also changed.

after i refresh the browser it went back to normal countdown without changing the timezone.

i wonder why can someone help me with this ? thanks in advance and also for grammar correction you are welcome to edit this question thanks thanks.

also, can someone explain this to me thanks again

[image: image attached]

update :

okay here's my full code

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime,gmt){
      var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(getCurrentDateByGMT(gmt));
      var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
      var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
      var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
      var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
      };
}
```

---

```
function initializeClock(hour,minute,second,endtime,gmt){
    var locHour = document.getElementById(hour);
    var locMinute = document.getElementById(minute);
    var locSecond = document.getElementById(second);
    if(!endtime){
        console.log(false);
    }else{
        function updateClock(){
            var countDown = getTimeRemaining(endtime,gmt);
        console.log(countDown);// here is the console that output the image above
            if(countDown.total>=0){
                locHour.innerHTML = ('0' + countDown.hours).slice(-2);
                locMinute.innerHTML = ('0' + countDown.minutes).slice(-2);
                locSecond.innerHTML = ('0' + countDown.seconds).slice(-2);
            }else{
                console.log("happend");
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
                initializeClock(hour,minute,second,generateTimerPerPeriod(),gmt);
            }
        }
        updateClock(); // run function once at first to avoid delay
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
    }
}
```

---

```
function generateTimerPerPeriod(){
    var schedule = [['00:00:00', '11:59:59'],['12:00:00', '15:59:59'],['16:00:00', '19:59:59'],['20:00:00', '23:59:59']];
    var currentTime = getCurrentDateByGMT(getTimezone('+8'));
    var currentPeriod = new Date(currentTime);
    for(var timeCtr = 0; timeCtr < schedule.length ; timeCtr++){
         var startDate = schedule[timeCtr][0].split(':');
         var endDate = schedule[timeCtr][1].split(':');
         if(currentTime > currentPeriod.setHours(startDate[0],startDate[1],startDate[2],0) && currentTime < currentPeriod.setHours(endDate[0],endDate[1],endDate[2],0)){
            var periodDate = new Date(currentPeriod.setHours(endDate[0],endDate[1],endDate[2],0));
//              console.log(" enddate " +periodDate);
            return periodDate;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
function getCurrentDateByGMT(finalTimezone){
    var myOldDateObj = new Date();
    var myTZO = -480;
    var myNewDate=new Date(myOldDateObj.getTime() + (60000*(myOldDateObj.getTimezoneOffset()-myTZO)));
    console.log(" newdate "+ myNewDate);

    var now = new Date();
    var localTime = now.getTime();
    var finalGMT = now.getTimezoneOffset() - finalTimezone;
    var localOffset =  finalGMT * 60000;  // where 60000 is equals to 1 min
    return new Date(localTime + localOffset);
}

function getTimezone(timezone){
    return timezone * (-60);
}
```

Update :

how about this one ?

```
function getCurrentTimeGMT8(){
    var d = new Date();
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var now = new Date(utc + (3600000*8));
    var hour = addZero(now.getHours());
    var min = addZero(now.getMinutes());
    var sec = addZero(now.getSeconds());
    var tz = "GMT+8";
    var time = hour +':'+ min +':'+ sec + " " + tz;

    return time;
}
```

Comment: hi guys im just a newbie about this topic i just gather information without knowing more about it , so if you are going to downvote it atleast consider drop a comment of corrections like what mr. matt did thanks thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. The `getTime` function of the `Date` object always returns values in terms of UTC, so calling it `localTime` is incorrect.  That means your `finalGMT` and `localOffset` values are also incorrect because you're assuming the `localTime` value has been adjusted for the local offset, and it hasn't.  Your code should just be:
2. Any time you construct a new `Date` by changing the underlying timestamp (like you do with `new Date(localTime + localOffset)`, and also when you create your `myNewDate` variable), you're not actually changing the time zone.  You're just moving the `Date` to a different moment in time, which is probably not the one you intended.  The `Date` object will *still* represent time in the current local time zone, and will still follow the DST transition rules for the current local time zone.  If you intended it to represent some other time zone, that can get in the way.

   Note that you can still calculate the UTC-based numeric timestamp from the current time via `Date.now()` (or via `Date.UTC` with user input values) and adding the desired offset.  You just can't then take that timestamp and put it in a `Date` object unless you intend it to reflect the *local* time zone.  If you need to know the year, month, day, hour, minute, second of that timestamp in any other time zone than the local zone, you'll need a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), or some advanced algorithms of your own.
3. You asked about changing the time zone in the OS.  You should recognize that the effect of this is inconsistent across browsers, versions, and operating systems. Many browsers (such as Chrome) will not pick up the new time zone until the browser process is completely terminated and restarted.  However, some browsers (such as IE) will update the time zone without requiring a restart.  If you need the user's time zone offset, you shouldn't cache it.
4. Keep in mind that a number can only represent an *offset*.  A *time zone* can have more than one offset, either due to daylight saving time, or due to changes over its history.  Read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

   In your case, your countdown timer is working only with *offsets*.  If that's your intent, then fine.  You can certainly take a date, time, and offset as input values. Just don't assume that the *current* offset from `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` will necessarily be the correct offset for *ALL* dates and times in the user's time zone.

Comment: this make things clearer, about moment.js its blocked on our office so i cant use it.. i really wanted to study more about moment.js but unfortunately i cant. btw thanks for this clarification i know from the start that i just changing the time not the timezone itself and i keep on finding a better solution ,  thanks thanks thanks